# Mongoose Virtual reference between two ObjectIds

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know it is possible to create a virtual reference using a local _id to a foreign ObjectId, but is it possible to use a local ObjectId to a foreign ObjectId?

I'm trying to figure out if I have a bug somewhere or if this is not possible because it's not working.

```
const Post = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
  }
})

const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
  },
  bio: {
    type: String,
    max: 500,
  }
});

ProfileSchema.virtual('posts', {
  ref: 'Post',
  localField: 'user',
  foreignField: 'user',
});

// query
const profile = await Profile.findOne({
  user: req.user.id,
}).populate('posts')
```

Comment: Please share you how you execute the query

Comment: updated @O'DaneBrissett

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett I figured it out. I forgot to set toJson virituals to true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you need to add `{ toJSON: { virtuals: true } }` to the Schema.

```
const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'user',
    },
    bio: {
      type: String,
      max: 500,
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  }
);
```

From docs:

Keep in mind that virtuals are not included in toJSON() output by default. If you want populate virtuals to show up when using functions that rely on JSON.stringify(), like Express' res.json() function, set the virtuals: true option on your schema's toJSON options.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals